# Wrong output LINQ Sum

Tags: c#, linq

I have this data below and linq query sum. But I don't know why its output is not what I expected.

**DATA**

> DateFiled -  TotalDays   -   Cancelled  - TypeId  - EmpId
>
> 05/04/17  -  2  - False  -  5  -  2
>
> 05/04/17  -  3  - False  -  5  -  2

**Linq Query**

```
var TotalDays = (from a in db.Headers
              join
              b in db.Details on a.HeaderId equals b.HeaderId
              where a.DateFiled.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && a.LeaveTypeId == 5
              && a.IsCancelled != true && a.EmployeeId == empId
              select a.TotalDays).Sum();
```

**Query Output**

> 13

**Desired Output**

> 5

Is there any wrong with my query?.

Comment: You have nothing to do with Details table so why are you joining with it?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad the details that I example is from the Table Header. They have a relationship as you can see in the join. Header and Details

Comment: can you add the entity classes of `Header` and `Detail` and provide the multiplicity between the two (eg: one-to-one, one-to-many)?

Comment: I think `join to db.Details` is redundant. It causes duplicated data, and you didn't use anything in `db.Details`

Comment: @kiRa you do not use any `Details` column in the where or select part of your query. So seems you may not need to join it (except some special senarios which is not mentioned)

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad both of the table is needed to be join that's why. And for the others. Its okay now. It solve by `Slava`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var TotalDays = (from a in db.Headers
              join
              b in db.Details on a.HeaderId equals b.HeaderId
              where a.DateFiled.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && a.LeaveTypeId == 5
              && a.IsCancelled != true && a.EmployeeId == empId
              select a).Distinct().Sum(a => a.TotalDays);
```

Comment: I will test it. Wait for a moment.

Comment: can be shorten?. like `... select a.TotalDays).Distinct().Sum()` ?

Comment: No, your variant will not work, if some TotalDays will be equal.